# Variables from Master Page always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have these variables set on my MasterPage

```
    public string CurrentUser = "";
    public string UserDomain = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        string[] userDetails = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        UserDomain = userDetails[0];
        CurrentUser = userDetails[1];
    }
```

In a child page I am simply trying to read those values back:

```
CurrentUser = ((SiteMaster)Page.Master).CurrentUser;
UserDomain = ((SiteMaster)Page.Master).UserDomain;
```

They are always coming back empty.
I can see that they are set correctly on the Master page but they get lost on the way to the content page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try adding inside `if(!IsPostBack) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Master page Load event comes after the Content page Load event. That probably means that the variables get initialized *after* they are accessed in your content page.

You could opt to set those properties in the `Init` event of the masterpage, or initialize them on accessing a property.

See [Events in ASP.NET Master and Content Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Where would the `Init` go? In the masterpage or the content page?